# Getting all tasks to which user has access

Tags: asana

I'm developing a desktop app with a backend. In the desktop app I just retrieve all tasks assigned to user, but on the web I have to get all tasks (including archived) to which Asana user had an access. Is there a convenient way to do that?

It looks now I have to do so:

1. Get all workspaces
2. Cycle though all workspaces and get all tasks.
3. Get all projects in a workspace
4. Cycle through projects and get all tasks
5. ? merge tasks from workspaces and projects. This should be done, because the task can be detached from a project.

**EDIT:**

It seems now is possible to have this way only:

1. /workspaces
2. cycle through workspaces to get all projects /workspaces/workspaces_id/projects
3. cycle through all projects to get tasks /tasks/?project=project_id

You get all tasks user has access to, but without tasks detached from projects (workspace tasks). How to get really all tasks, is a question

Regards,
Victor

Comment: Are you sure getting tasks from the workspaces isn't sufficient? If a task is in a project it won't be listed under the tasks from a workspace?  Your idea sounds right.  I think it should be: 1. Get all workspaces associated with a user, 2. Cycle through workspaces and get all tasks and 3. filter tasks based on assignee, completed and whatever else.

Comment: I used asana ruby wrapper. It looks it uses /tasks path always. This endpoint accepts project_id OR workspace_id AND assignee_id. Maybe I should try to use "/workspaces/workspace-id/tasks" path. Anyway it would be very convenient to have something like /tasks?user_id=11111 to retrieve all tasks to which user has an access to.

Comment: Nope, the path "/workspaces/workspace-id/tasks requires "assignee" parameter

Comment: Victor, I thought you said you wanted to use the "assignee" parameter. Also, your proposed solution gets all the tasks for the workspace. My point is that querying all the projects is unnecessary as the workspace contains all the tasks in the projects. I misspoke about filtering based on assignee, since the initial workspace query does that already. But my main point stands.

Comment: Oh, I see your edit.  This question was answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711840/listing-all-asana-workspace-tasks

Comment: Basically, they don't provide a way to do this because it would require many, many, requests.  They want people to be making smaller queries, like all projects associated with one user, or one project.  A task with no assignee and no project cannot be found through the API if I understand correctly.  That seems like a poor way to be using Asana anyway.